# How to pass parameter from MVC Controller to Angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am using Angular in MVC Project.  To change views I pass the URL to my Angular controller like this:

In my Angular Module:

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap', 'checklist-model', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pagination', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.exporter', 'ui.grid.autoResize', 'ngRoute'])
```

In my MVC Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ConfigureDefaultLayout();


            return View("ContractorOperatorView");

            //return PartialView("_ScoringSetOverride");
        }

        public ActionResult GetContractorPage(int companyId, string currentStatus)
        {   
            contractorId = companyId;
            ReleaseStatus = currentStatus;
            string newUrl = "/SSQV4/SSQV5/Contractor/Index";
            return Json(newUrl, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Then in my Angular Controller:

```
$scope.rowDblClick = function (row) {
    generalsearchService.goToContractorPage(row.entity.CompanyID, row.entity.ReleaseStatus)
    .success(function (data) {
        $window.location.href = data;
    })

};
```

In my Angular service --

```
this.goToContractorPage = function (id, status) {
    return $http.post('/SSQV4/SSQV5/Contractor/GetContractorPage', { "companyId": id, "currentStatus": status })
};
```

All worked fine as I was making the "contractorId" static in my MVC controller, but that is causing functionality problems.  I need to pass the contractorId along with the URL to my Angular controller, but I don't know how.  I tried this:

In my MVC Controller --

```
 string newUrl = "/SSQV4/SSQV5/Contractor/Index?id=" + contractorId;
```

Then in my Angular controller --

```
$scope.contractorid = $routeParams.id;
```

I receive the error "routeParams is undefined".  I know that there must be some way to do this, but I am clueless has to how.  There is a lot of information on passing parameters from Angular to MVC, but not much on the reverse.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

I tried putting this in my app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap', 'checklist-model', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pagination', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.exporter', 'ui.grid.autoResize', 'ui-router'])
$stateProvider.state('contractor', {
    url: '/Contractor?contractorId',
    params: {
        contractorId: {
            value: null,
            squash: true
        }
    }
});
```

Now I get "$stateProvider is undefined" error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use the ui-router Angular module , you need to define the parameter in your state definition:

```
  $stateProvider.state('contractor', {
    url: '/contractor?contractorId',
    params: {
      contractorId: {
        value: null,
        squash: true
      }
    }
  });
```

And then of course you need to inject the $routeParams into your controller before using it.

Comment: I am unable to get any of this to work, mainly because I don't understand what $stateProvider is doing and where to put all of the code.  What goes into my MVC Controller?  Currently I have this:             contractorId = companyId;
            ReleaseStatus = currentStatus;
            string newUrl = "/SSQV4/SSQV5/Contractor/ContractorOperatorView?contractorId=" + contractorId;
            return Json(newUrl, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  Am I passing it correctly? If so how do I retrieve the contractorId that is passed?

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js file make sure to add on that a route that there will be a parameter. [Check out here.](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing)

> Often, URLs have dynamic parts to them which are called parameters. There are several options for specifying parameters. A basic parameter looks like this:

```
$stateProvider
.state('contacts.detail', {
    url: "/contacts/:contactId",
    templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html',
    controller: function ($stateParams) {
        // If we got here from a url of /contacts/42
        expect($stateParams).toBe({contactId: "42"});
    }
})
```

> Alternatively you can also use curly brackets:

```
// identical to previous example
url: "/contacts/{contactId}"
```

> Examples:
>
> '/hello/' - Matches only if the path is exactly '/hello/'. There is no special treatment for trailing slashes, and patterns have to match the entire path, not just a prefix.
>
> '/user/:id' - Matches '/user/bob' or '/user/1234!!!' or even '/user/' but not '/user' or '/user/bob/details'. The second path segment will be captured as the parameter 'id'.
>
> '/user/{id}' - Same as the previous example, but using curly brace syntax.
>
> '/user/{id:int}' - The param is interpreted as Integer.

I Hope it is helpful.

Comment: So the curly brackets go in my MVC controller like this: string newUrl = "/SSQV4/SSQV5/Contractor/Index?{contractorId}"?  I'm confused as to where to put the code you provided and how exactly am I retrieving the contractorId in the Angular controller?  Is the $stateProvider retrieving the contractorId?

Comment: Nope they'll go in your 'state' definition in your app.js file. There is an example in the code above. In your new url will be the actual contractor id value. Also don't forget to inject $routeParams into your controller.

Comment: I tried adding the suggested code to my app.js file, now I get the error "$stateProvider is undefined".  See edits to my question above.

Comment: Somewhere it's not being injected. Don't use the `?` query string syntax, use the `route1/route2/:param` syntax. Then in your controller you should be able to access `$stateParams.param`. I'm a little confused with your code. Check out the documentation link I sent you. Get a better understanding of the UI Router.

Comment: so I use route1/route2/:param in my MVC Controller?  I did look at the documentation that you sent me but it does not mention the MVC Controller at all so I'm confused as to how to tie it all together.

Comment: In your state definition all you have to do is change your url to this `$stateProvider.state('contractor', {
    url: '/Contractor/:contractorId',
    templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html',
    controller: function ($stateParams) {
        var contractorId = $stateParams.contractorId;
    }
});`

2. Access that value in your controller.

When you go to your new state provide the param.
var newUrl = "/SSQV4/SSQV5/Contractor/" + contractorId;

Comment: This is still not working.  In my app.js I have this:  var app = angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap', 'checklist-model', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pagination', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.exporter', 'ui.grid.autoResize', 'ui.router'])

app.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('Contractor', {
        url: '/SSQV4/SSQV5/Contractor/ContractorOperatorView/:contractorId',
        templateUrl: 'ContractorOperatorView.cshtml',
        controller: function ($stateParams) {
            var contractorId = $stateParams.contractorId;
        }
    });
});

Comment: In my MVC Controller, I have this:         public ActionResult GetContractorPage(int companyId, string currentStatus)
        {   
            contractorId = companyId;
            ReleaseStatus = currentStatus;
            string newUrl = "/SSQV4/SSQV5/Contractor/ContractorOperatorView/" + contractorId;
            return Json(newUrl, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }